# How to limit the use of certain character sets

Tags: android, validation

I hope this question isnt going to be down-flagged for not showing some actual code, but thats the core of this situation. I simply have no clue where to start to solve this issue, even after trying to use several combinations of keywords on both Google, and here on SO.

My client suddenly decided that half of the Android App I'm developing for him has to be Chinese, so after I have made some changes in the Database so some fields can take in Simplified Chinese character sets, I need to make sure that my client (living in holland) only uses those characters in that particular EditText field in the app. (There are more Database fields that now only allow Simplified Chinese, however these values come from a dropdown list in the app, so I dont need to worry about wrong characters for them).

So how would one make sure that only Simplified Chinese is used in an EditText field?

Comment: with localisation, its all or nothing, no two ways about it. Do it partial, it is not a good thing to have and would appear unfinished and unprofessional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a project in Ruby that attempts to detect whether characters are Traditional Chinese, Simplified Chinese, or Japanese (maybe others?): https://github.com/jpatokal/script_detector

This detection is based on the [Unihan Database](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/), in which there is a file called Unihan_Variants.txt. (Download zip file containing this text file [here](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Unihan.zip).)

Conceivably, you could parse the txt file into a lookup table and check the unicode value as the text is entered during onTextChanged() for your EditText. However, the readme on the project linked above states: "It is important to understand that this requires long sections of text to work reliably, since a single character or even several characters may be valid Japanese, traditional Chinese and simplified Chinese simultaneously." So, weeding out characters on an individual basis might prove difficult.

Comment: thanks for the idea. It seems that if this fails, ill just have to go with it like this and maybe just send a Toast to the user whenever the Database finds out some non-Chinese characters are used.